# How to send message like whatsapp, telegram, viber or imo just between two person?

Tags: node.js, firebase, security, socket.io, chat

I want to create a messenger app like whatsapp,

1. First I need to make a list of people connected to my messenger app.
2. I want to message to one of the person which existed on the list, so I click on its name on the list.
3. Now I want to chat with him.

Here I don't want message gets broadcast to all people.

So please show me the best secure way.

I've done some like below code.
I am just created a room only between two person
this works well.
but problem is when two person for the first time and the same time click each other to go messaging there two different rooms gets create.
if they click each other from the list for the first time in different time then it works well.

```
(async () => {

    try {
    
        const r1 = await AsyncStorage.getItem(userphone + "u-uuuuuuuu-u" + mynumber);
        const r2 = await AsyncStorage.getItem(mynumber + "u-uuuuuuuu-u" + userphone);
    
        if (r1 !== null || r2 !== null) {
            if (r1 !== null) {
                this.socket.emit("joiningroom", { room: r1 });
                if (this._isMounted) {
                    this.setState({ room: r1 });
                }
            } else {
                this.socket.emit("joiningroom", { room: r2 });
                if (this._isMounted) {
                    this.setState({ room: r2 });
                }
            }
    
        } else {
    
            var ref1 = db.collection('chatrooms').doc(userphone + "u-uuuuuuuu-u" + mynumber);
            var ref2 = db.collection('chatrooms').doc(mynumber + "u-uuuuuuuu-u" + userphone);
    
            const doc1 = await ref1.get();
            const doc2 = await ref2.get();
    
            if (doc1.exists || doc2.exists) {
    
                if (doc1.exists) {
                    const room = doc1.data().mbaliotaq;
                    this.socket.emit("joiningroom", { room });
                    if (this._isMounted) {
                        this.setState({ room });
                    }
                    await AsyncStorage.setItem(userphone + "u-uuuuuuuu-u" + mynumber, room);
                } else {
                    const room = doc2.data().mbaliotaq;
                    this.socket.emit("joiningroom", { room });
                    if (this._isMounted) {
                        this.setState({ room });
                    }
                    await AsyncStorage.setItem(mynumber + "u-uuuuuuuu-u" + userphone, room);
                }
    
            } else {
    
                const id = userphone + "u-uuuuuuuu-u" + mynumber;
                const room = "mmm" + userphone + "r-rrrrrrrrr-r" + mynumber + "mmm";
    
                db.collection('chatrooms').doc(id).set({
                    mbaliotaq: room
                }).then(() => {
                    this.socket.emit("joiningroom", { room });
                    if (this._isMounted) {
                        this.setState({ room });
                    }
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
            }
        }
    
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(`Error in async ${e}`);
    }

})();
```

I need a better way and a secure way than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating chat rooms create create message objects which will have a messageId, senderId, receiverId, time, text,etc...

and in back-end check send messages based on usersId

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I have a list of users and I want to save messages in db and I need to chat always with them, so there every time users gets connect socket has different id. now I dont know what is the solutions

Comment: while registering give a user a unique id which will be used for chats so that id doesn't change

Comment: thank you Vinil, Could you please give me an example?

Comment: User: `const user = { email: String, id: String, name: String });`

store users data when registering

Message:  `const message = { messageId: String, senderId: String, receiverId: String, time: Number, text: String });`

Comment: Thank you I've done something like this, but my problem is chat one person I click on its name, although there are more than 10 person online. for example:
user1, user2, user3, ......
Now I want to message just to user1
even he is not online he must receive my message when gets online

Comment: when user is online filter all messages with his id in senderId or receiverId and show all messages

Comment: thank Vinil, unfortunately I am new to socket.io I have to find a complete example.